# Как вырезать скругление у блока?

Tags: css, css3, svg

Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью CSS сделать такой блок.
Задний фон белый и цвет блока белый, для их отделения используется тень, но через эту самую тень блок отображается неправильно. Есть у кого идеи как это можно реализовать?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.block {
  position: relative;
  width: 417px;
  height: 592px;
  padding: 45px 30px;
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #dbdbdb;
  background-color: #fff;
}

.block:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: calc(40px * 2);
  height: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  border-bottom-left-radius: calc(40px * 2);
  border-bottom-right-radius: calc(40px * 2);
  box-shadow: 0 5px 20px #dbdbdb;
}
```

```html
<div class="block"></div>
```

Comment: В чём именно неправильность?

Answer (score 5):

Еще один svg вариант

```
M 0 0              // встаем в точку 0 0
h 40               // рисуем линию вправо на 40
a 10 10 0 0 0 20 0 // рисуем дугу радиусом 10 до точки, которая находится на 20 вправо
h 40               // рисуем линию вправо на 40
v 140              // рисуем линию вниз на 140
a 5 5 0 0 1 -5 5   // рисуем дугу радиусом 5 до точки, которая находится на 5 влево и на 5 вниз
h -90              // рисуем линию влево на 90
a 5 5 0 0 1 -5 -5  // рисуем дугу радиусом 5 до точки, которая находится на 5 влево и на 5 вверх
z                  // замыкаем фигуру
```

```html
<svg viewbox="-10 -10 120 170">

  <defs>
    <filter id="shadow">
      <feDropShadow dx="0" dy="0" stdDeviation="4" flood-color="rgba(0,0,0,0.3)" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <path fill="white" filter="url(#shadow)" d="
    M 0 0 
    h 40
    a 10 10 0 0 0 20 0
    h 40
    v 140
    a 5 5 0 0 1 -5 5
    h -90
    a 5 5 0 0 1 -5 -5
    z
  "></path>
</svg>
```

Comment: не еще один, а единственный хороший!) я свой уберу)

Comment: @HamSter ну зачем же так, Вы ведь старались :)